# i m a new to java. I already have added the while condition but eclipse still asking for it

Tags: java

I am new to java and I stuck with very simple code. I already have added the `while` condition, but eclipse still asking for it.

Error:

> Syntax error, insert `while (Expression);` to complete BlockStatements

Code:

```
 package assignment517;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Products {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     do{
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the number of product");
       int numberOfProduct=input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter the products sold");
       int productsSold=input.nextInt();

       double pprice = 1.0;

       switch(numberOfProduct){ 
         case 1: {
           System.out.print("Price of total products sold");
           System.out.print (pprice= 2.98*productsSold);
           break;
         }

         case 2: {
           System.out.print("Price of total products sold");        
           System.out.print(pprice= 4.50*productsSold);
           break;
         }

         case 3: {
           System.out.print("Price of total products sold");
           System.out.print(pprice= 9.98*productsSold);
           break;
         }

         case 4: {
           System.out.print("Price of total products sold");
           System.out.print(pprice= 4.49*productsSold);
           break;
         }

         case 5:{
           System.out.print("Price of total products sold");
           System.out.print(pprice= 6.87*productsSold);
           break;
         }

         default:{
           System.out.print("invalid value");
         }

       }while(numberOfProduct !=6);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste in the full error message it's giving you?

Comment: Remove the `{}` from your case statements.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` is misplaced - it should be after the close `}` of the `do`, not of the `switch`. Note that since it relies on the `numberOfProduct` variable, you need to move its definition outside the do-while loop.

Comment: Thanx eveybody, issue has been resolved......